# How do I add multiple email addresses to an SSL certificate via the command line?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I know that by adding/modifying the `SubjectAltName` entry in `openssl.cnf` this [can be achieved](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm), but is there a way to do so without having to modify that file every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to mess around with the `openssl.cnf` file in any way.

The following command demonstrates how to generate a self-signed certificate with SAN for the email `nobody@example.com`:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
  -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj '/CN=Nobody' \
  -extensions san \
  -config <(echo '[req]'; echo 'distinguished_name=req';
            echo '[san]'; echo 'subjectAltName=email:nobody@example.com')
```

The trick here is to include a minimal `[req]` section that is good enough for OpenSSL to get along without its main `openssl.cnf` file.

In OpenSSL ≥ 1.1.1, this can be shortened to:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes \
  -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj '/CN=Nobody' \
  -addext 'subjectAltName=email:nobody@example.com'
```

Here we are using the new `-addext` option, so we don't need `-extensions` and `-config` anymore.

Don't forget to verify the contents of the generated certificate:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in example.crt
```

See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/198409/133603 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366949/19163

Answer (score 1):

In `openssl.cnf` at the top add the entry `SAN = "email:copy"` (to have a default value in case the environment variable `SAN` is not set) and in the respective section use `SubjectAltName = ${ENV::SAN}`. Now just call `SAN="email:copy, email:adress@two" openssl ...`, where `email:copy` makes sure the main address is used as well. (Adapted from [here](https://library.linode.com/security/ssl-certificates/subject-alternate-names))

Comment: note to self: If your only access is via SSH, make sure your `openssl.conf` is valid. The simplest check is trying to establish a second connection (or `scp` something) without cutting the first one